# When running flutter app on iOS real device getting below errors. working fine in android and iOS simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

/fullpath.../ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/Compression.swift:59:25: warning: 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead
return try data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes:UnsafePointer) -> Data in

```
                        ^
/fullpath.../ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/Compression.swift:83:29: warning: initialization of 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>' results in a dangling pointer
            strm.next_out = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(&buffer)
                          

/fullpath.../ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/Compression.swift:83:57: note: implicit argument conversion from '[UInt8]' to 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>' produces a pointer valid only for the duration of the call to 'init(_:)'
            strm.next_out = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(&buffer)
                                                       

/fullpath.../ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/Compression.swift:83:57: note: use the 'withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer' method on Array in order to explicitly convert argument to buffer pointer valid for a defined scope
            strm.next_out = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(&buffer)
                                                        

/fullpath.../ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/Compression.swift:145:33: warning: initialization of 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>' results in a dangling pointer
                strm.next_out = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(&buffer)
                                

/fullpath.../ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/Compression.swift:145:61: note: implicit argument conversion from '[UInt8]' to 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>' produces a pointer valid only for the duration of the call to 'init(_:)'
                strm.next_out = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(&buffer)
                                                            

/fullpath.../ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/Compression.swift:145:61: note: use the 'withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer' method on Array in order to explicitly convert argument to buffer pointer valid for a defined scope
                strm.next_out = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(&buffer)
                                                           

/fullpath.../ios/Pods/Starscream/Sources/Starscream/Compression.swift:140:14: warning: 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead
        data.withUnsafeBytes { (ptr:UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
             

Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
While building module 'AVFoundation' imported from /fullpath.../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player-1.0.1/ios/Classes/FLTVideoPlayerPlugin.m:6:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
```

`/Volumes/MyData/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVFoundation.h:15:9: fatal error: 'AVFCore/AVFCore.h' file not found #import <AVFCore/AVFCore.h>`

```
1 error generated.

/Volumes/MyData/Flutter_Data/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player-1.0.1/ios/Classes/FLTVideoPlayerPlugin.m:6:9: fatal error: could not build module 'AVFoundation'
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

2 errors generated.


Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
```